# what is the problem to run c code by visual studio and its run successfully, vs to run the same code in linux (ubuntu) using MAkefile with geany

Tags: c, ubuntu, data-structures, terminal, geany

i have a problem when i compile a c language code  in visual studio is running perfectly but when i compile it in ubunto (Makefile using geany) i got this message:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
i thought the problem from this function:

```
    void count_words(WordCount **wclist, FILE *infile) 
    {
      char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
        char* str;
        FILE* fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            str = new_string(word);
            int len=strlen(str);
            for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
                str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
            }
            
           
            add_word(wclist,str);
            // printf("%s\n", &word);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

the full code is:
main.c:
/*
Word Count using dedicated lists
*/

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "word_count.h"

/* Global data structure tracking the words encountered */
WordCount *word_counts = NULL;

/* The maximum length of each word in a file */
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 64



int num_words(FILE* infile) {
  int num_words = 0;

char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
  FILE *fp = fopen(infile,"r");
        while( fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF )
            num_words++;  
  return num_words;
}


void count_words(WordCount **wclist, FILE *infile) 
{
  char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    char* str;
    FILE* fp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        str = new_string(word);
        int len=strlen(str);
        for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
            str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
        }
        
       
        add_word(wclist,str);
        // printf("%s\n", &word);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}


/*
 * Comparator to sort list by frequency.
 */
static bool wordcount_less(const WordCount *wc1, const WordCount *wc2) {
  //return false;
  
    return (wc1->count - wc2->count);

}

// In trying times, displays a helpful message.
static int display_help(void) {
    printf("Flags:\n"
        "--count (-c): Count the total amount of words in the file, or STDIN if a file is not specified. This is default behavior if no flag is specified.\n"
        "--frequency (-f): Count the frequency of each word in the file, or STDIN if a file is not specified.\n"
        "--help (-h): Displays this help message.\n");
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Handle command line flags and arguments.
 */
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    
    
  // Count Mode (default): outputs the total amount of words counted
  bool count_mode = true;
  int total_words = 0;
 
  // Freq Mode: outputs the frequency of each word
  bool freq_mode = false;

  FILE *infile = NULL;

  // Variables for command line argument parsing
  int i;
  static struct option long_options[] =
  {
      {"count", no_argument, 0, 'c'},
      {"frequency", no_argument, 0, 'f'},
      {"help", no_argument, 0, 'h'},
      {0, 0, 0, 0}
  };

  // Sets flags

  while ((i = getopt_long(argc, argv, "cfh",long_options, NULL)) != -1) {
      switch (i) {
          case 'c': 
              count_mode = true;
              freq_mode = false;
            
              break;
          case 'f':
              count_mode = false;
              freq_mode = true;
            
              break;
          case 'h':
             
              return display_help();
      }
  }

  if (!count_mode && !freq_mode) {
    printf("Please specify a mode.\n");
    return display_help();
  }

  /* Create the empty data structure */

  init_words(&word_counts);

  if ((argc - optind) < 1) {
    // No input file specified, instead, read from STDIN instead.
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];   
    infile = stdin;
    infile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "w");
    if(infile!=NULL){
    while(fgets(word,MAX_WORD_LEN,stdin)!=NULL)
    fputs(word,infile);
    fclose(infile);
    }
    total_words =num_words("myfile.txt");
    remove ("myfile.txt");

            }
  else {
    
     int current_sum=0;
     if(count_mode)
     while (optind < argc )
     {
         current_sum=num_words(argv[optind]);
         printf("%d  %s \n",current_sum,argv[optind]);
         total_words+=current_sum;
         optind++;
         
        }
        else
        if(freq_mode)
          count_words(&word_counts,argv[optind]); 
         

   }

  if (count_mode) {
    printf("The total number of words is: %i\n", total_words);
  } else {
    
    wordcount_sort(&word_counts, wordcount_less);

    printf("The frequencies of each word are: \n");
   fprint_words(word_counts, stdout);
  
}
 

  return 0;
}
```

word_count.c:

```
#include "word_count.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
/* Basic utililties */

char *new_string(char *str) {
  return strcpy((char *)malloc(strlen(str)+1), str);
}

void init_words(WordCount **wclist) {
  /* Initialize word count.  */   
   *wclist=NULL;     
}
   
size_t len_words(WordCount *wchead) {
    size_t len = 0;
    WordCount  *current = wchead;
      while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        len++; 
        current = current -> next; 
    } 
    return len;
}

WordCount *find_word(WordCount *wchead, char *word) {
  /* Return count for word, if it exists */
 WordCount *wc;
    wc = wchead;
    WordCount *equal=NULL;
   // int result;
    while (wc != NULL)
    {
        
            if (strcmp(wc->word, word) == 0)//equal
                  equal=wc;
                  
            wc = wc->next;
    } 
    
    return equal;
}

void add_word( WordCount **wclist, char *word) {
  /* If word is present in word_counts list, increment the count, otw insert with count 1. */
 WordCount* new_node = (WordCount*)malloc(sizeof(WordCount));
        WordCount *last = *wclist;
    new_node->word = word;
    new_node->count = 1;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (*wclist == NULL)
    {
        *wclist = new_node;
        return;
    }
   /* WordCount *wcc=find_word(*wclist,word);
    if(wcc!=NULL)
    { 
        printf("present");
        wcc->count++;
        return;
        }*/

    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = new_node;
    return;       
}

void fprint_words(WordCount *wchead, FILE *ofile) {
  /* print word counts to a file */
  WordCount *wc;
  for (wc = wchead; wc; wc = wc->next) {
    fprintf(ofile, "%i\t%s\n", wc->count, wc->word);
  }
}
```

word_count.h:

```
struct word_count {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct word_count *next;
};

/* Introduce a type name for the struct */
typedef struct word_count WordCount;

/* Initialize a word count list, updating the reference to the list */
void init_words(WordCount **wclist);

/* Length of a word count list */
size_t len_words(WordCount *wchead);

/* Find a word in a word_count list */
WordCount *find_word(WordCount *wchead, char *word);

/* Insert word with count=1, if not already present; increment count if present. */
void add_word(WordCount **wclist, char *word);

//static int wordcntcmp(const WordCount *wc1, WordCount *wc2);

/* print word counts to a file */
void fprint_words(WordCount *wchead, FILE *ofile);

/* Inserts a word into the list in order. Assumes the existing list is already sorted */
void wordcount_insert_ordered(WordCount **wclist, WordCount *elem, bool less(const WordCount *, const WordCount *));

/* Sort a word count list in place */
void wordcount_sort(WordCount **wclist, bool less(const WordCount *, const WordCount *));
void printList(WordCount** wclist);

#endif /* word_count_h */
```

Comment: How do you compile it, what args?

Comment: Run the program in a debugger. The debugger can show you where the segmentation fault occurs. (This is not necessarily the cause of the problem.) Or run it with Valgrind like this: `valgrind ./your_program`

Comment: The problem is bugs in your program, which we probably not going to find for you as the code is big. "Running on system A, but failing on system B" is the regular symptom of a bug invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: One issue noticed from a quick scan. In function `static bool wordcount_less()` you `return (wc1->count - wc2->count);` Was that meant to be `return (wc1->count < wc2->count);` ?